# Crashes from Most Recent App Store Build Not Being Symbolized in Xcode Organizer

Tags: xcode, symbolicate, crash-log

I am able to view Crash Logs in my Xcode 7 Organizer, but when I view my current App Store version, the Crash Logs are not symbolized. I can view older versions fine.

Any idea why my latest App Store build would not be symbolizing?